# An algorithm of step-wise sampling from higher dimensional joint distribution, is it valid?

Tags: sampling, joint-distribution

In a simple example, assume joint distribution $\{X,Y,Z\}\sim F_{XYZ}$

The algorithm works as follows:

1. Sample $x$ from the marginal distribution of $X$, $F_X$.
2. Sample $y$ from the distribution of $Y$ conditional on $x$ and marginal on $Z$, $F_{Y|x}$.
3. Sample $z$ from the conditional distribution of $Z$ on $x$ and $y$, $F_{Z|x,y}$.

Does the resulting $\{x,y,z\}\sim F_{XYZ}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_conditionally_dependent_variables

Comment: Exactly how do you sample $y$ conditional on $Z,$ *which you haven't yet observed??*

Comment: @whuber, oops, I meant conditional on $x$ and marginal on $Z$. I'll correct.